# fiddler http request and virus

Tags: fiddler, virus

My laptop is likely infected by virus as the q key sometimes automatically input itself,  but not responding to my click. 
I want to see if there are any suspicious things going on throug Internet,  eg keyboard logger. 
I open fiddler to see the http request and find the following
Host:
ohkdapdekh (and some similar random strings)
Url:
/

And a lot of 
Tunnel to talkx.l.  Google.com:443

I don't use google talk... only once a few weeks before

Now I would like to know is there any way to track what program or service is making the request?
Please help and rescue my dear computer.

Comment: Sounds more like a broken q key than a virus

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest scanning for and removing the virus instead of trying to track it's http requests. If you really want to know, using TCPView (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) will allow you to see what process is making the request.

Otherwise, I would suggest using MalwareBytes and ComboFix to remove the virus. Make sure to take a backup first of any important data as usual before attempting malware removal.